# Isn't everything block-storage? (File-storage, object-storage, block-storage)

Tags: filesystems, storage, object-storage, file-storage, block-storage

I try to distinquish the known storage types File-, Block- and Object-Storage and I am stuck on one point for hours now:

In the end, on any type of storage data is stored as blocks of bits on a drive, isn't it?

And is "File-Storage" not the same as "file/folder based, hierarchical organized magagemend/representation on a block storage"?

It seems to me that the terms File- and Object-Storage are more about the concept of organizing and managing data whereas block-storage is more about the underlying implementation of storing the data in the end?

Can someone enlighten me please

Answer (score 5):

The type of storage (file, block or object) depends upon the type of interface exposed externally to users or applications.

While internally, all the types of storage may be block storage, what matters is how this storage is exposed - for read & write to external parties such as users, applications or even other storage systems (e.g. for augmenting storage)

Comment: Ok, thats a good point thank you. I was investigating further on and ended up at the topic storage virtualization. Based on what i read there I think distinguishing on the interface level is a good idea since this whole field is way more abstract nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

I came to the scheme:

**block** = data

**file** = block + metadata (name, size, author etc.)

**object** = file + metadata (anything)

PS: trying to understand the basics too. Correct me if I'm not right, please.